# Release pipeline powershell task to use a file in azure repository for temp download of file (how to story)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-repos

This should be a stupid simple thing to do...
Simply need to use a powershell task to download a .js file from an azure repository using the powershell task tell the azure agent server to run a command to import the .js  into a mongodb load file.

This is new to me but I did some looking into how. What I came up with.

```
#Download to local path from Azure Repository
$organization = "HappyBalloons"
        $project = "99RedBalloons"
        $repository = "BagofBalloons"
        $path = "/api/red2/front-end-happy/_Mike99Balloon.js"
        $version = "99main"

        
        $pat = "$(System.AccessToken)" 

        $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))

        $url = "https://dev.azure.com/repositoryURL"

        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method Get

        # Download File
        $response.content | Set-Content -Path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/downloaded-files/_Mike99Balloon.js" -Force
      
     

     #FilePath
      $FilePath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/downloaded-files/_Mike99Balloon.js"
```

do I really need a project PAT?
or is there a better way I can't see (forest for the trees kinda thing)

```
$pat = "$(System.AccessToken)" 

        $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
```

so I updated the

```
$pat = "$(System.AccessToken)" to be "$env:System_AccessToken"
```

Seems to work now. or at least doesn't choke on it.

Comment: Why not use the `checkout` step to check out the repository?

Answer (score 0):

Check this api [Items - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP#examples):

Example:

```
$user = ""
$token = "<pat>" 

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$org = "<org>"
$project = "<team_project>"
$repo = "<repo_name>"

$localfilepath = "c:/temp/<filename>"
$devopsfilepath = "/<path_to_repo_file>"
$fileurl = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repo/items?scopePath=$devopsfilepath&download=true&api-version=7.2-preview.1"

function InvokeDownloadRequest ($GetUrl, $filepath)
{   
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -OutFile $filepath
}


InvokeDownloadRequest $fileurl $localfilepath
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Release pipelines, you can include a repository as an artifact, and then those files will be automatically downloaded onto the agent for the stages you configure it to be included on.

[image]

Comment: This feature is not limited to release pipelines. Release pipelines are largely legacy at this point; YAML pipelines are the modern equivalent and support the exact same thing.

Comment: His question stated he was using a Release Pipeline, so I answered with how it can be easily accomplished in a Release Pipeline.

Comment: I was actually asking about the legacy release pipelines. Only problem is the repository the file is located on is basically folder with half the source code on it. ::sigh::